# Please allow the uploading of images

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, images

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Feature request: Image upload](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4376/feature-request-image-upload)

I know that [uploading arbitrary files is out of the question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4637/feature-request-file-upload), but it could be very useful to be able to upload a screenshot or some king of graph (UML, Schema, etc.) when answering some question.

Even though there exist several places to host images, but keeping them in the same server as the answer would give some confidence that the uploaded image will be there as long as the answer itself.

It could block outside requests to avoid some server load, and require some outstandish ammount of rep to upload, but it would be genuinely usefull.

Comment: Duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4376/feature-request-image-upload

Comment: I voted to close for duplicate and then I realized only me and the Skeeter can vote right now. Then I flagged for moderator attention.

Comment: @TheTXI -  I totally would have voted to close...

Comment: I voted to close in my head.

Comment: rofl @ the closers list

Comment: Please get your accounts combined (34813 & 130127)