# Upload pics and images to posts

Tags: support, images, screenshot

Alas, I have found my posts in need of visual accompaniment and yet, I find not the mechanism to attach such images herein.

How, fine people of the support to Stack Overflow, does one attach a `.png` or `.jpg` file to their post?

Comment: while this technically probably belongs to superuser.com I think we should keep it here

Comment: Nope, this belongs on meta.stackoverflow.com

Comment: (Where it'll be closed as a dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4376/please-allow-image-uploads-directly-onto-the-site http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4811/please-allow-the-uploading-of-images-closed

Answer (score 3):

On Windows, you can install [Cropper](http://cropper.codeplex.com), and there are [plugins](http://cropperplugins.codeplex.com) to "Send to TinyPic" or "Send to ImgUrl" .    The way these plugins work, you take a snapshot of the screen or the current window, and it is auto-magically uploaded.  The clipboard is populated with the short URL for the direct image.

At that point, in your SO post, you need only Ctrl+G, and then Ctrl-V, and you have an image in your post.

Very fast, very simple.

[image]

There is also a "Send to Paint.NET" plugin for Cropper if you want to doctor up the image before posting it.

Cropper and the cropper plugins are separate downloads, but both free.

Answer (score 1):

1. Upload your image to a free file server, such as picasaweb.
2. Click ctrl+G, enter in the image of the url
3. You are done.