# Ability to upload code samples (ie: entire zipped project)?

Tags: feature-request, source-code

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Please add a system to allow file uploads attached to questions and answers.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4637/please-add-a-system-to-allow-file-uploads-attached-to-questions-and-answers)

It would be nice to be able to upload entire projects in a zip file to SO would it not??

Likely there would have to be some form of cap on file size and what not, but I don't think this should cause too much of a problem in terms of additional bandwidth costs, and it would come in handy for a lot of situations.

Comment: Dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4637

Answer (score 6):

Nobody wants to deal with your entire project :) Many are happy to help with specific parts. Specific parts can be pasted in any of the many pastebin services online.

A young man asked what was wrong with his program earlier today, and posted a link to hundreds of lines of code - I politely encouraged him to be more specific with his description, and code-sample. I  get the feeling this would be the general community-opinion.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't upload images, I doubt this will be implemented

If you want to upload samples you could use one of the many free storages online

Comment: Image hosting has *not* been declined: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4376/