# Submit large chunk of code to pastebin

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Sometimes it is good to have complete output or more details on the code being executed.

Pasting it on the main question/answer makes it difficult to read even with the scroll bars that appear.

Wouldn't it be useful to have some functionality to submit certain parts of the code to some other place like [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) for instance?

---

#### Background:

The question that made me suggest this functionality is here:

> [Analyzing data from same tables in different db instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1337216/)

You can see in the last edit that there is more to post, but it was put on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/).

I'm not really dying for this or anything, I seldom post questions of this length, but I think this might be useful.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4637/please-add-a-system-to-allow-file-uploads-attached-to-questions-and-answers/4646#4646

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have a problem with posting things to pastebin (I say it is useful in many instances), but I don't think there needs to be any type of built-in functionality to make that process faster than it already is.

Comment: Mmhh yeap. Also, it is not that super difficult ( I mean to manually paste )

Comment: Wow, further proof of failure from our random sort.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why anything on SO.com needs to change. Post your code on pastebin and put the link in your post.

Your answer should be discouraged BTW. You should have a handle on your problem and you should be able to post a terse explanation without all of the code being necessary. You could post multiple terse questions if needed as well.

Answer (score 1):

Jeff has said before he doesn't want to necessarily facilitate the use of large amounts of code. It's a somewhat rare problem, and when it is an issue there are ways to solve it (as you demonstrated above). There's no real need to integrate this, and I fear that if it ever were integrated, new users would feel it was acceptable to post thousands of lines of code asking for reviews, or help finding a single error in the haystack.