# Attach Files in stackoverflow

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, attachment

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Please add a system to allow file uploads attached to questions and answers.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4637/please-add-a-system-to-allow-file-uploads-attached-to-questions-and-answers)

Its my doubt. is there any way to attach files in stackoverflow along with the posts. For example if we want to post our project files etc.

Comment: Not possible and not needed. If you want someone to look in the whole code, better to contact such person in private and send it in email anyway.

Comment: Please don't try to do this.  If you can't ask a question without dumping a metric ton of code, your question isn't worth asking.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you find yourself thinking you need to attach project files, you have probably not done enough research yourself. To quote http://tinyurl.com/so-hints :

> That means if you want me to look at
>   code, it should:
>
> ...
>
> - Be as short as possible. If I have to wade through hundreds of lines of
>     code to find the problem, I'm doing
>     work that you should be doing. Often
>     if you work hard to reduce the problem
>     to a short but complete program,
>     you'll find the issue yourself. You
>     can absolutely do this without knowing
>     what the problem is; you should be
>     looking to the community for their
>     expertise, not their willingness to
>     spend time on your problem doing the
>     work that you can do yourself.

Answer (score 1):

No, i don't think so
But you can upload anywhere and post just a link to your files..
https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=file+upload+free

Comment: You *can*, but you shouldn't.