# is it possible to upload test data file together with my post?

Tags: discussion

There is no choice to upload a test data file in stackoverflow ,although an image is OK.
The data file is just 2M. I will post my code and compare my result with other people.

If not possible,is there any alternative method?

Comment: You shouldn't need 2m records in order to create a test-environment. You should be able to do it with less than 10 normally...

Comment: Alternative is to provide [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) - short example file that will demonstrate your issue. About ten lines or so. Or short script that will generate a test file for readers, if your issue arises when processing big files. If you really need a diagnosis on a given file, or you wish to do some pooling about it, probably you are here for wrong reasons.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a recommendation of free hosting site

Comment: possible duplicate of [Please add a system to allow file uploads attached to questions and answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4637/please-add-a-system-to-allow-file-uploads-attached-to-questions-and-answers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put that file on a public file sharing site and put that public url along with your post.

Check the following sites:

1. [Drop box](https://www.dropbox.com/)
2. [Paste Bucket](http://pastebucket.com/)
3. [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/)

Comment: I thought it should be a general question. Many people should need that. Could you please recommend one site?

Comment: @questionhang: for files like images, zip files etc drop box is best, for pasting huge amount of code pastebin/pastebucket can be used. (My personal opinion I use dropbox, and it's best)

Comment: Got it.Thank you very much.