# How do I upload a data file to Stack Exchange?

Tags: support, attachment

I want to ask a question in Stack Exchange with a data file. I'm new to Stack Exchange & I don't how to post my excel data file here.

I'd be grateful if anyone can tell me how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

You can't upload a data file.  See [Jeff Atwood's answer to "Please add a system to allow file uploads attached to questions and answers"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/4643/148310).

In general, you should strive mightily to make each question (and answer) self contained.  Minimize the need for data files as much as you can.

See:

- [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackapps.com/help/how-to-ask)
- [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)